# How to make this code thread safe? ID++; Print_Value (ID);

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I am new to `C++` but I need to code something in multithread way. In the following code, if `Increase_value()` is called by more than one thread, what is the most efficient way to make sure that `Print_Value()` prints the `ID` value that `Increase_value()` had initially increased. In other word, how to make sure that during the run, `Print_Value()` prints a sequence of numbers without any missing any value (the order of numbers is not an issue).
Could using atomic variables discussed in `C++11` help here?

```
class foo 
{
   public:
      static int ID;
      void Increase_value() 
      {    
           ID++;  
           Print_Value (ID-1);
      }
      void Print_Value(int k)
      {
           cout << k ;
      }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could using atomic variables discussed in C++11 help here?

Definitely. I would say the simplest way of making your code thread-safe is to make `ID` an `std::atomic<int>`:

```
#include <atomic>

class foo 
{
  public:
      static std::atomic<int> ID ;
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      void Increase_value() 
      {    
           int old = ID++;  
           Print_Value (old);
      }
      void Print_Value(int k)
      {  cout << k ;   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment just before you reply to it. I was trying to gather more information... Thank you Andy.